# Difference Between from and of in time preposition

Tags: grammar

I received an email from my college saying that

**Exam can be withdrawn within 60 mins of the finish of the exam**

Can we replace the "of" with "from" ? And if no, how will it change the meaning of the sentence if we use from.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you say "within 90 days after"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108403/can-you-say-within-90-days-after) '[There is] an element of ambiguity present in [such] constructions. Although “within 30 days [of]” is often interpreted as meaning “within 30 days after”, it can also be interpreted as “within 30 days before or after”. Typically, one interpretation or the other is obvious, and after need not be explicitly mentioned..' @jwpat7 I'd always rephrase here. And using 'from' doesn't clarify conclusively.

Comment: I think it is ambiguous. Is it intended to mean "60 minutes _before_ the end of the exam, 60 minutes _after_ the end of the exam or both? any of those interpretations is possible as it stands. Replacing 'of' with 'from' implies 60 minutes _before_ to me but others might interpret it differently.

Comment: The email is saying if my exam gets over at 10:00, I can withdraw the paper before 11:00. So can we use from ?

Comment: You have just added the clarification 'The email is saying _if my exam gets over at 10:00, I can withdraw the paper before 11:00_'. Where does _this_ come from? It is not made clear in your actual _question_ as posted. 'Exam can be withdrawn within 60 mins of the finish of the exam' is ambiguous and thus violates a Gricean maxim of acceptability (the maxim of _manner_).  Substituting 'from' does not clarify.

Comment: As I said in original comment I interpret the statement "...withdrawn 60 minutes  _from_ the finish of the exam" to mean the exact opposite of what you describe. I'm not saying that I'm definitively correct, others may well disagree, but I am sure that there are those who would interpret it in the same way. It's like describing a race and saying that the person lying second overtook the leader 5 metres from the finishing line and held his lead.

Comment: Based on a clarifying comment, the sentence should be different: *The exam can be withdrawn **for up to** 60 minutes **after** its finish.*

Comment: Why would they write so ambiguously in a formal email ? If I do use from, for example the line is "exam can be withdrawn from within 60 mins from the the finish time" what is the meaning of this line ? And in what cases from can be used ?